# Having trouble defining an object of type FileList and File in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a form to submit to an API that has an image of type `FileList`.

The first image in FileList at `image[0]` of type `File` looks like this:

[image]

So my API receives an image of `File` type above and I'm trying to set my Form type so it gets a proper image type.
This is what my form's type looks like:

```
type FormValues = {
  ...
  image: string | File;
};
```

I want to extract only the `name` property from this object. I also want image to either be a `string` or a `File` type. As I'm trying to extract a `name` property such as `form.image.name` I get a following error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | File'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

I've failed at defining an object of type `File` with a `name` property in it. I understand what I have to do, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.htm), type guards in particular here.

```
type FormValues = {
  // ...
  image: string | File;
};

function isFile(value: string | File): value is File {
  return value instanceof File;
}

const form: FormValues = {
  // ...
  image: new File(["file contents"], "example.jpg", { type: "image/jpeg" }),
};

if (isFile(form.image)) {
  console.log("Image name:", form.image.name);
} else {
  console.log("Image:", form.image);
}
```

You can also use `as` type assertion if you're sure that the image is a File in that specific case, however that defeats the purpose of typechecking imo.